# What can I use as a key if I don’t have an ID property in my data?

Tags: reactjs

I have an array of objects fetched from an API where each object does not contain an ID property. Sometimes the properties contain the same values as other objects, so there isn't a clear object property I can use as an ID.

What can I use as a key when iterating over this array? Is it safe to use `index`?

I tried no key, which prompts React to print a "missing key" warning.

I used the index while mapping over the array, which suppressed the warning, but I know this is a bad practice:

> We don’t recommend using indexes for keys if the order of items may change.

Source: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys

Comment: "if the order of items may change" this is basically what you need to worry about. The key is so that react can match already existing DOM elements to objects in the array allowing react to only update what is necessary. If you swap keys react will not be able to match the existing elements for update and will either need to update more than necessary or delete and recreate the DOM elements. If you reorder objects in an array their index will change, which means they will be given a different key. If you don't reorder, remove or insert within (at the end is fine) then you should be fine.

Comment: The key is just has to uniquely identify the element. It doesn't need to have an `id` in the slightest, it could be its label content, or even a combination of properties that allow you to point at _specifically that element_ when looking at a bunch of them and you need to find it. So: show what your element looks like, which should allow folks to tell you what would be a reasonable key.

Answer (score 0):

As the doc says, you shouldn't use an `index`.

If you have an array `[a, b, c, d]`, b has index 1, and you add an element to this array at the beginning `[d, a, b, c]` b will have index 2 (a and c will obviously have new indexes too).

When you look at the new doc, it talks about the `uuid()` package.
The problem with this solution is that each time you render a new element, it will have a new key.
I haven't found a better solution yet.

By the way, the new react doc, source: https://react.dev/learn/rendering-lists#keeping-list-items-in-order-with-key